# Чем милиция отличается от полиции (с точки зрения лингвистов, разумеется)?

Tags: этимология

Чем они отличаются фактически, это другой вопрос.))) Но вообще оба термина обозначают по сути одно и то же, так почему разница в названиях? И еще почему "полицейский", но "милиционер", хоть слова совершенно однотипные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полиция (фр. Police, от др.-греч. ἡ πολιτεία — государство, город) — система государственных служб и органов по охране общественного порядка. Т.е. уже изначально полиция - это, то, что связано с государством.

Латинский же термин "militia" (милиция) первоначально обозначал службу солдата-пехотинца (лат. miles).
Со времени учреждения постоянных армий милицией стали называть особый тип армии, которая формируется только на время войны, и таким образом является разновидностью ополчения. Примером такого формирования является Национальная гвардия США.
Термин "милиция" в значении "органы охраны общественного порядка" изначально произошел из установления Временного правительства, заменившего после Февральской революции "царскую" полицию "народным ополчением", занятым охраной порядка. Смысл переименования заключался не только в стремлении избавиться от определения де Кюстина русской полиции как ведомства, занятого сокрытием преступлений вместо их профилактики и расследования, но и в признании факта, что охрана правопорядка должна проводиться в жизнь не закрытой кастой — полицией — а всем народом. В дальнейшем термин "милиция" был воспринят правительством Советской России, а также впоследствии распространился на территории и страны, попавшие в сферу влияния СССР.

Что же касается суффиксов "-ск" и "-ер", тот уж кроме так сложилось ничего не попишешь. Единственное, слово "полиция" в русском языке появилось раньше. Судя по всему именно благодаря этому, её сотрудники получили более русское наименование, а милиционер "опросторечиться" не успел, хотя словари Ушакова и Ожегова существительное "милицейский" фиксируют.

http://www.vedomstva-uniforma.ru/svu.html

По ссылке можно прочитать, о особенностях милиции Временного правительства и что слово "милицiонеръ" использовали уже тогда. Вопреки behemothus  эпитеты "народная", "рабочая" и пр. применялись только к самой милиции, но не её сотрудникам.

Answer (score 2):

Касательно "суффикса".
Конечно же это просто "не так сложилось". Т. е. оно конечно и так, и сложилось, но не просто. Начнем с того, что "милиция" изначально была именно "народной милицией", официально упрощение произошло уже позже, лет, не соврать через десять после её создания (возрождения) большевиками.

"Миллиционер" было специально образовано (не уверен даже, при ВП или Советской власти) именно для того, чтобы чем-то противопоставить царской полиции. 
До 17-го года это было нормальным явлением, называть должности субстантиватом, только из более или менее близких по сфере: городовой и городничий, околоточный, присяжный поверенный и проч. "Милицейский" - не проходило бы, он же замышлялся как ополченец, т. е. это не гос. должность, да и "народный милицейский" - многовато будет (мотивы можно переосмысливать, но суть не изменится).
Для решения и было выдумано совершенно искусственное "милиционер", ни в одной стране не ведомое, его даже не очень понятно, как надо писать, по-французски например.

Я вот очень хотел бы узнать, как называли римского "милиционера" времен Республики (V век до н. э.). miles - это уже, вроде бы, вторичное...

Comment: Изначально действительно вышел декрет Временного правительства от 10.03.17 г. об упразднении Департамента полиции. Была провозглашена замена полиции "народной милицией". Только официальное наименование её было просто милиция и называют её народной, чтобы не путать с "рабочей милицией" Советов. Первая упразднена большевиками 28.10.17, вторая же же в итоге стала "рабоче-крестьянской милицией" и в этом наименовании просуществовав как минимум до конца ВОВ, потом "советская милиция".

Только всё эти определения относились к милиции, а не милиционеру. Он наименования не менял.

Comment: >Только официальное наименование её было просто милиция   
  
Источник? 

>После Февральской революции 1917 года в России царская полиция была ликвидирована. Была провозглашена замена полиции "народной милицией".  
Читать далее: http://rapsinews.ru/incident_publication/20110301/251951397.html#ixzz2Y6YfFGi7 

Вроде недвусмысленно. Как раз название "рабочая" появилась позже, при советской власти.

Впрочем, в сугубо лингвистических рамках моих рассуждений это совершенно без разницы. "Рабочий милицейский" звучут еще нелепее "народного".

Comment: Так что все-таки появилось раньше, слово miles/milita или сам римский "ополченец" этим словом называемый? Сдается мне, что должно у него быть  какое-то название, отлиное от милиционера... Хотя, может, я действительно уже вне темы... ладно, не буду грузить.

Comment: Ну, хотя бы тут можно посмотреть названия документов, "народной" нигде нет. http://www.adhdportal.com/book_3127_chapter_9_Zlam_polejjsko_sistemi_Rosjjsko_mper_v_khod_revolju_1917_r.Mlja_Timchasovogo_urjadu._Stvorennja_ml_msevikh_rad.html

"Милиционеры" мне попадались в документах 1918 года, но на уровне постановления ГорСовета, на более высоком слово появляется только с появлениям звания "милиционер".

В принципе слово вписывается в эпоху (революция-революционер, милиция-милиционер), милицейский (рабочий) тоже бы подошло, но...

Comment: >так что все-таки появилось раньше, слово miles/militia или сам римский "ополченец" этим словом называемый?

Скорей всего сперва ополченец, а потом (почти одновременно) слово, обычно в таком порядке происходит, но времена далёкие утверждать не берусь.

Comment: Значит, все-таки то, что мы имеем сейчас, это полиция (в России она теперь так и называется, а у нас на Украине — еще нет), а не милиция.

Comment: @FuchoinKazuki Именно. Реформа Медведева в этом плане восстановила корректный смысл. Правда, только ради этого затевать её...